# Mediawiki - Extra URL Parameter in LanguageSelector Extension

Tags: php, mediawiki

In my MediaWiki, I'm using the LanguageSelector extension which basically adds `setlang=language_code` to the URL.

Now, I would like one of my custom extensions to get a certain parameter from the URL. Let's say **/w/MainPage?dbid=12345**. Wiki doesn't use dbid so the page will load just fine, and my extension will pick it up. The problem is, the LanguageSelector doesn't see that parameter and removes it, opening the page with URL **/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&setlang=de**.

Is it possible to change the LanguageSelector extension in a way to make the dbid= parameter persist throughout the language change?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
$dbid = $_GET['dbid'];
if ($dbid != NULL) {
 $html .= Html::Hidden( 'dbid', $dbid );
}
```

at line 387 of the LanguageSelector Extension seems to have worked.